# Does Model.populate() return a promise?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

I am following a guide on Node.js and Mongoose. Developing some code for an eCommerce store. I have two code snippets, both use populate() on a Model however one code snippet requires execPopulate() to return a promise but the other doesn't. I have tried removing execPopulate and adding it to the other method but I get errors on both.

[image]

[image]

Any explanation is welcomed and appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Populate()` return `«Query» this` see [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) and according to mongoose [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises) again `Query` is not a promise.

> Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a .then() function for co and async/await as a convenience. However, unlike promises, calling a query's .then() can execute the query multiple times.

So if you want to use populate as a promise use [execPopulate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-execPopulate)